# Excel — keep leading zeros in text string

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, text-formatting

For Excel associated with Microsoft Office 2016:
I have seen answers to keeping leading zeros in Excel for a number, but how does one keep the leading zeros displayed for a text string (taken from a TSQL-varchar):
e.g.
000A0
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append an ' (apostrophe) character in front of the string to force Excel to treat it as a string.

You might also have luck if you preformat your cell as text.